# Material Properties Gone On Final Render

Tags: rendering

I've been using Blender 2.92 for about a week now to create some sports NFTs. I've created a card of sorts with which rotates and have added material properties like metallic, sheen, clearcoat, etc to have the object look as if its glass. However, once I start to render, the image is 'flat' meaning that none of those settings applied (no shine, no reflection, etc).
I've attached two screenshots to show what I'm seeing the viewport (what I want to see) vs what the render looks like.
[image: Render]
[image: Viewport]
Not sure what other settings/info needs to be provided so please reply with what I need to provide.

Comment: Here is a link to better show how I want the final product to look when rendered. This was created by using my Macs screen record feature
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FGWxrxUjluM

Comment: mix shader nodes probably? Use your image as one input and other glossy/glass material as another input and play with settings until you get what you want. Also you can import images as planes and it may be a better solution for this kind of task

Comment: Really don't understand what you're saying. All images were uploaded as planes. Once the images were arranged on the slab, I joined them all together.